# JQuery PopUp mouse move

Tags: jquery

How can i move a jquery popup window by mouse click and move?

Comment: Aren't jQueryUI dialogs draggable by default?  Isn't there a "draggable" option to the setup parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/01/jquery-resizable-draggable-resize-drag-tutorial-example.html)

Here's a tutorial about how to make a pop up moveable.

Summarising, with the correct dialog plugin:

`$('#mydiv').draggable();`